# How to understand あえない in わかりあえない

Tags: translation, meaning

「わかり**あえない**」
I can guess that it is: Don't find understanding. But I'm not sure in it due あえない
I tried to find the answer and I met the verb **会える**. But I could not find the word in the dictionary. I guess it's almost the same as that **会う**
Thanks for your help!

Comment: If I write 分かり合う, does that help you?

Comment: Yes, I have understand

Answer (score 4):

わかりあえない is a **negative potential** form of わかりあう (分かり合う）

> わかりあ**う**：To understand each other / to comprehend 
>   わかりあ**える**：(potential form) **Able** to understand each other / comprehend
>   わかりあ**えない** : (negative-potential form) **Not** **Able** to understand each other / comprehend